# Map parent-child table to other tables based on row type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

We have an child-parent hierarchy with extra tables & fields for each item type (up to 100 types).

The `FOREIGN_KEY` column in `TBL_COM_RELATION` references to the record in a data table. Now we want to access the tables via Entity Framework on ASP.NET Core.

These are the tables that I have created on a SQL Server DB:

`TBL_COM_RELATION`

[image]

`TBL_COM_TYPE`

[image]

`TBL_DATA_CUSTOMER`

[image]

`TBL_DATA_ORDER`

[image]

The models in C#:

`Model.ComRelation`

```
[Table("TBL_COM_RELATION", Schema = "dyn")]
public class ComRelation
{
  [Key]
  public Guid ID
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public int? FOREIGN_KEY
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public int TYPE_ID
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public virtual ComType ComType
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public Guid PARENT_ID
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public virtual ComRelation Parent
  {
     get; set;
  }

  [ForeignKey("ID")]
  public virtual ICollection<ComRelation> Children
  {
     get; set;
  }
}
```

`Model.ComType`

```
[Table("TBL_COM_TYPE", Schema = "dyn")]
public class ComType
{
  [Key]
  public int TYPE_ID
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public string DESC
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public string TARGET_TABLE
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public string TARGET_CLASS
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public string TBL_FOREIGN_KEY
  {
     get; set;
  }
}
```

`Model.Customer`

```
[Table("TBL_DATA_CUSTOMER", Schema = "dyn")]
public class Customer
{
  [Key]
  public int CUST_ID
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public string Name
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public string Street
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public string City
  {
     get; set;
  }
}
```

`Model.Order`

```
[Table("TBL_DATA_ORDER", Schema = "dyn")]
public class Order
{
  [Key]
  public int ORDER_ID
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public string Description
  {
     get; set;
  }
}
```

Is it possible use a `DbSet<ComRelation>` and inherit dynamically based on the item type?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "inherit dynamically". if you're talking about inheriting from the models, then i believe then answer is no. But it could be possible to encapsulate, if your models share some properties.

Comment: I want to have a base class (the relation) and each type (customer, order) inherit from this

Comment: You can't do that at runtime, but what you can do is either use a decorator, or strategy pattern, depending on what you're trying to achieve. You could simply wrap an object, and use whatever functionality you need from it along with the functionality and properties of the class wrapping it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to "inherit" or build dynamically the relations based off table data. However, you can implement a generic method and retrieve the related object based off of a known type.

```
public T GetObject<T>(int id)
{
    return context.DbSet<T>.Find(id);
}
```

Usage:

```
public object GetRelatedObject(Guid relationId)
{
    var relationType = context
                       .DbSet<ComRelation>
                       .Join(context.DbSet<ComType>, r => r.TYPE_ID, t => t.TYPE_ID, (r, t) => new { Relation = r, Type = t })
                       .Where(r => r.ID = relationId)
                       .FirstOrDefault();

    Type objectType = Type.GetType(relationType.Type.TARGET_CLASS, "Namespace"), 
         contextType = context.GetType();

    var method = contextType.GetMethods()
                 .Where(m => m.Name == "GetObject" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
                 .FirstOrDefault()
                 .MakeGenericMethod(objectType);

    return method.Invoke(contextType, new object[] { relationType.Relation.FOREIGN_KEY });
}
```

The `GetRelatedObject` method will return an object of type `Customer` or `Order` which you will need to process accordingly.

HTH